# How to find the data that Have status 9 but still did not have status 10

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select slog.filename, doc.d , doc.sap_id
from document_state doc, serv_log slog
where
  doc.exeid = slog.exeid
  and doc.timestamp < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1
  and doc.timestamp> TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 55
  and doc.document_status = 9
  and slog.exeid not in (
    select exeid from document_state 
    where document_status >= 10
  )
group by
  slog.strs_filename,
  doc.sys_id, 
  doc.sap_id;
```

I wrote this query for to find the data that have status 9 and it did not have status 10 , but I executed my query and it took so long time , any idea to speed up this query

Comment: Group by is not needed in your query. And instead of not in use not exists.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: iam new in sql , how it can be the final query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following query which should ideally perform better.

```
select distinct slog.filename, doc.d , doc.sap_id
from document_state doc join serv_log slog on doc.exeid = slog.exeid
  Where doc.timestamp < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 1
  and doc.timestamp> TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 55
  and doc.document_status = 9
  and not exists (
    select 1 from document_state d 
    where document_status >= 10
      And slog.exeid = d.exeid
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the documents using:

```
select ds.*
from document_state ds
where ds.document_status = 9 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from document_state ds2
                  where ds2.exeid = ds.exeid and ds2.document_status = 10
                 )
```

You can join to additional tables and then add additional filtering using this as a base.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't a `having` clause does what you want?

```
select l.filename, d.sysid, d.sap_id
from document_state d
inner join serv_log l on d.exeid = l.exeid
where
    d.timestamp < trunc(sysdate) - 1
    and d.timestamp> trunc(sysdate) - 55
    and d.document_status in (9, 10)
group by s.strs_filename, d.sys_id, d.sap_id
having max(d.document_status) = 9
```

Note that I replaced `doc.d` in the `select` clause with `doc.sysid`, so the `select` clause is consistent with the `group by` clause.